# Running a windows batch script in a separate process

Tags: windows, scripting, batch

I want to start a long running process from a windows batch file. The start script should just call the second script and return, end. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Start LongProcess.exe
```